# Using setuptools to create a package -- change of the case of some directories

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Python 3.5, setuptools 34.3.2, Mac OS 10.12

I am creating a package for some libraries I've been writing. I'm using for that:

```
python3 setup.py sdist --format=zip
```

It works fine and I get a package I can distribute to other systems.

Now, my code has several directories, all of them named in lower case. When I create the zip file, the case is changed in two of them:

```
documentation -> Documentation
spice -> SPICE
```

The documentation directory (which contains all the docuemntation created with Sphinx) is not a problem as everything seems to work. Actually, I seem to remember that the Documents folder always uses capital letter, for some reason. The other, however, is a python package used in other parts of the code and, as a consequence of this change from lower case to upper case, the package is not found anymore.

I can not find any reason why, when creating a package, those folders - in particular the "spice" folder - changes. It is very annoying an problematic since it prevents me to use my code properly.

Do you have any suggestion about what might be going wrong here?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post the output of the command? Also, please include the input folder tree and output zip structure. Thanks

Comment: Problem solved!! Edited question above with the solution.

Comment: I suggest you post the answer also.

Comment: Done! Many thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

PROBLEM SOLVED!

When creating a package, there is some information stored in a folder named "mypackage.egg-info". This folder had (very) outdated information corresponding to a time when the names of the directories where different.

The solution has been as simple as removing that folder and execute the command to create the package again.